# Select picker bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have done some code to bind names into dropdownlist with JQuery and it works fine, but a senior programmer asked me to add other code to my existing code.

html:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
     <select id="sel_group" name="group_id"  class="bs-select form-control input-medium">
        <option value="">Select Group....</option></select>
 </div>
```

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var url_list = "api/usergroup/getdata";
$.getJSON(url_list)
.done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, obj) {
        $("#sel_group").append("<option value='" + obj.id + "'>" + obj.name + "</option>")
        console.log(obj.name);
    })
});
```

});

his code:

```
$(".bs-select").selectPicker({

iconBase: 'fa',
tickIcon: 'fa-check',
```

});

but when I added his code to my code it did not work for me and I am not sure why he wants me to add this code?

Comment: add the bootstrap select js to your project https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: so you meant that bootstrap select is not added in my project? but I have added the bootstrap library.. is that excluded from library?

Answer (score 1):

This is what he meant, probably (*I made dummy JSON array*): [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9L3jdup/1/)

Dependencies you should have in your project for this to work:

> https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
>   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js
>   http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

You need to add class *show-tick* in select:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="sel_group" name="group_id"  class="show-tick bs-select form-control input-medium">
        <option value="">Select Group....</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Also, I don't have access to your methods, so I made some dummy JSON array. It should work anyways:

```
$(".bs-select").selectpicker({
        iconBase: 'fa',
        tickIcon: 'fa-check'
    });

$(document).ready(function () {

    var url_list = "api/usergroup/getdata";

    var obj = [{'id': 25, 'name': 'Amel'}, {'id': 7, 'name':'Legend'}];

    /*$.getJSON(url_list)
    .done(function (data) {*/
    $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value);
        $("#sel_group").append("<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.name + "</option>").selectpicker('refresh');
    });
    //});
});
```

In the end, he wants this ticks like this:

[image]